# Error 0x80073CF9 while installing my wp 8.1 app

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, windows-10-mobile, windows-store

I'm developing an application windows phone 8.1.Previously, it worked fine on Windows Phone 10 and Windows Phone 8.1, but after one of the Windows 10 updates, the app is no longer installed from the Windows Store. The installation is crushed with 0x80073CF9 error. All I found about this error in the Google is advices for Win Phone users, not for developers. Logs obtained from the device indicates a crash during installation, it also did not help me.
I checked if there is in my project proscribed names, or library, rid of all warnings. Cleaned project. But nothing helps. According to the disgruntled responses of users I can see that they can not install it too. There is no errors while create package and publishing it to Store: this is the most confusing as it is not clear what went wrong and what hinders to install the application on the device. 
I am developing in Visual Studio 2015.
Did someone face similar problems?

**UPDATE**

I tried all the tips have been found in Google including correction time and language settings, soft reset, hard reset and many others. Result still the same.

Comment: this is the generic error message ERROR_INSTALL_FAILED. can you post the store link so that I can try it on my Lumia 950XL with Win10M 14393

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have read about this issue, and even get some logs, but they are not very informative for me. Here the link: https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/store/p/mywebmoneytest1/9nblggh40gqb

Comment: @dmitriy, I try to install your app on my Lumia 950 with Windows 10 14393, but I fail to do it. The best practice for you is to contact [Dev Center Support](http://aka.ms/storesupport) through your developer account so that you may get more professional help. Please share your solution if you solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT I have already sent  request to the support center. It was on Friday. Still waiting for answer.

Comment: I also fail to install it via store and via the Appx I got via proxy link. In the Manifest XML I see some wired **m3:** entries. remove them in the **.appxmanifest** and rebuild the appx. now try to install it. I also see from the XML that you use VS2015. Try to build the app via VS2013 and look if this makes a i difference.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks for the reply!
Please tell me what kind  wired m3: entries? I did not change it manually, all setting up using Visual Studio designer.

Comment: I just created a package in Visual Studio 2013. Unfortunately did not help.

Comment: I looked at the **AppxManifest.xml** and see **<m3:Capability Name="contacts" />** this m3 annoys me.

Comment: I tried to delete all capabilities and create a package. Published it to store. App still do not installing. Apparently m3 entries are not the reason. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @dmitriy, I am also having this issue, did you find a solution? Thanks

Comment: @raver99, no, I still can't figure out what's wrong with my app. Long days chatting with MS suport has no result: they adviced verify app's name, and check capabilities. I tryed everithing in differend order - nothing of that is works. So I just ported my app to Silverlight 8.1.